# Report Fotter Settings In Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

in my report footer section, I insert a sub report as summary for my main report, even I set  "print at bottom"  by section expert, the position of report footer is sometime at top when the current page is empty, and sometime at bottom when the current page has content.

Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to print something at the bottom of the page, try to put it into page-footer, not into report-footer. But in any case it will work only in pageable output types (pageable/pdf, pageable/html), won't work in table/rtf, table/html, table/xls.

Comment: I run sub report in report footer and set fixed position in Pentaho Report Designer its sets the property in report designer but when I run from  JAVA API then if details part is empty then report designer not set at bottom of page ..If I use Page Footer then sub report can't run in page footer...

Answer (score 0):

If your footer data does not depend on data in your "details" report, then you can "reverse" your sub-reports hierarchy: put your details into another subreport, and nest it into your "footer" sub-report. Then you'll be able to use data of the "footer" sub-report on page footer section and your "details" sub-report in report-header section of "footer" sub-report. I guess, that would be most stable approach to your task.

Consider following Schema:

```
    "parent-report (use summary datasource)"
    |-page-header section
    |-report-header section
    | |-"detailed report (use detailed datasource)"
    |   |-details section
    |     |-<your details>
    |-details section
    |-report-footer section
    |-page-footer section
      |-<Your summary data from summary datasource>
```

Remember to set pagefooter's page-behaviour properties properly: set "sticky" to false, so that it will not be printed on each page.
Set "display-on-first-page", "display-on-last-page" as required.